# Image upload check in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am wondering should i go for `old method` or something new for image upload check  in `magento 2`?

`<?php if(isset($_FILES['image']['name']) and $_FILES['image']['name']!="") ?>`

any other solution?

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism it is not related to uploading the image or file. i am asking for replacement of this code

Comment: Check Marius answer basically the upload factory does all the checks for you if I remember right

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism nope i have to go for if else condition to do something. i have to put this before using any library.